# Get filename of current RDLC report

Tags: vb.net, reportviewer, rdlc

I need to get the filename of the current `RDLC` being displayed on the `ReportViewer`. Is there something like

```
Dim filename As String = Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.GetFilename?
```

because I do not want to do the following.

```
Dim path As String() = Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath.Split("\")
Dim filename As String = path(path.Length - 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any members in the [ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.reportviewer_members%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or its [LocalReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.winforms.localreport_members%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property to enable you to do this.

However, you might be able use a method like [Path.GetFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename.aspx) to do something like:

```
Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath)
```

So you're not doing the string split operation etc.

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with `NKVU's answer` and additionally, If you want to get the `filename` without its `extension`, You can use [**this**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx),

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath)
```